# вызов метода внутри одного класса

Tags: java

есть два метода в одном классе, первый ищет минимальное и максимальное значение в массиве  **public  void min_max()** , во втором нужно вызвать первый метод для смены минимального и максимального значения местами.

**public  void min_max()**

```
 public  void min_max(){
        int[] numbers = {15, 18, 19, 18};
            int idMin = 0;
            int idMax = 0;
        int min = numbers[0];
            int max = numbers[0];
int count =0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            if(min == numbers[i]){
                count++;
            }
            if(min>numbers[i]) {
                min = numbers[i];
                idMin = i;
            }
            if(max<numbers[i]) {
                max = numbers[i];
                idMax = i;
            }
        }
        }
```

---

```
 public  void change_MinMax() {

    **здесь нужно вызвать public void min_max() для смены местами максимального и минимального элемента массива**

            numbers[idMin] = max; 
            numbers[idMax] = min;

            for(int j = 0 ; j < numbers.length; j ++){
                System.out.print(numbers[j] + ", ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос-то? Нужно - вызывайте, разве ж вам кто-то запрещает?

Comment: Если вы хотите получить внятный ответ, задайте внятный вопрос. "Нужно вызвать" -- это не вопрос. Читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и другие темы там же.

Comment: fori1ton, во втором методе change_MinMax() вызвать min_max(), дабы не дублировать код, взять минимум и максимум

Comment: m. vokhm, если я допишу "КАК Нужно вызвать" это много изменит? суть описана в теме поста, если есть ответ по теме, буду весьма признателен

Comment: @аноним, вы рассуждаете так, как будто кому-то нужно решить вашу проблему больше, чем вам самому. При беглом прочтении суть вашего вопроса непонятна, многие (включая меня) просто пройдут мимо, не вникая -- люди часто бывают заняты своей работой, и разгадывать ребусы им некогда. Почему вы считаете, что тут кто-то вам что-то должен? Если вы хотите получить ответ от более опытных коллег, проявите немножко уважения к ним и потрудитесь задать свой вопрос понятно. К тому же у этого сайта есть правила, ваш вопрос их нарушает и он вполне может быть удален раньше, чем вы получите ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {15, 18, 19, 18};
        int minValIdx = getMinIndex(numbers);
        int maxValIdx = getMaxIndex(numbers);
        change_MinMax(numbers, maxValIdx, minValIdx);
    }

    public static int getMinIndex(int[]numbers){
        int valIdx = 0;
        int val = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i<numbers.length;i++){
            if(numbers[i] < val){
                val = numbers[i];
                valIdx = i;
            }
        }
        return valIdx;
    }


    public static int getMaxIndex(int[]numbers){
        int valIdx = 0;
        int val = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i<numbers.length;i++){
            if(numbers[i]> val){
                val = numbers[i];
                valIdx = i;
            }
        }
        return valIdx;
    }

    public  static void change_MinMax(int[]numbers, int idMax, int idMin) {
        int min = numbers[idMin];
        int max = numbers[idMax];
        numbers[idMin] = max;
        numbers[idMax] = min;

        for(int j = 0 ; j < numbers.length; j ++){
            System.out.print(numbers[j] + ", ");
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нужно минимум и максимум взять с метода  min_max(), вопрос как?

Comment: вам нужны индексы минимума и максимума. Разбейте первый метод на два. Пусть каждый из них возвращает int - индекс в массиве. Перый getMinIndex() второй getMaxIndex().

Comment: Добавил в ответ вариант решения

Comment: Z.John, все заработало, еще буквально вопрос в одном методе находился поиск минимума, максимума и подсчет их количества, но метод VOID, есть ли смысл создать 3 метода которые будут возвращать мин\макс и подсчет их кол-ва?

Comment: Хорошим тоном считается, что метод должен выполнять только одно действие, это способствует повторному использованию метода в др. местах. Заметьте, что массив чисел в эти методы так же приходит в виде входного параметра, таким образом данные методы можно использовать повторно с любыми целочисленными массивами.